# accessing label outside of listview

Tags: .net, label

I use label in  of listview,in code behind,I want to access label and
  set its text when button is clicked.but when i clicked on button, nullrefrace 
   `exception`   is `thrown

```
**.aspx Code:**

      <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" 
      `onselectedindexchanged="labeltext"` 
            onselectedindexchanging="la">
        <ItemTemplate>  
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
      <asp:Button ID="Button1" CommandName="select" runat="server" Text="Button" />

        </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:ListView>

**.aspx.cs:**
              protected void labeltext(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             Label list = sender as Label;

            ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)list.NamingContainer;
            Label lable = item.FindControl("Label2") as Label;
            lable.Text = "you click me";
        }

        protected void la(object sender, ListViewSelectEventArgs e)
        {

            Label1.Text = "rr";

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ListView list = (ListView) sender;
Label lable = list.FindControl("label2") as Label;
```

Comment: but still exception is thrwing

Comment: You didn't provide enough code. There was no code for your button. The event handler you provided did not handle the button event - where is the OnClick event handler for the button

Comment: I apply event selectedindexchanged on listview and set commandname="select" for button ",due to which two event are arised .I catch these events